# Hartl's Rails Tutorial Section 3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've been working through Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial, and for some reason I've gotten stuck on the first exercise in section 3.  I've checked and rechecked my code to ensure that it matches his, but I still get this error:

```
Failures:

  1) Static pages Contact page should have the content 'Contact'
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('Contact')
       expected #has_content?("Contact") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:48:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Static pages Contact page should have the title 'Contact'
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact")
       expected #has_title?("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.09624 seconds
8 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:46 # Static pages Contact page should have the content 'Contact'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:51 # Static pages Contact page should have the title 'Contact'
```

Here is my code

static_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Home'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
    end
  end

  describe "Help page" do

    it "should have the content 'Help'" do
      visit '/static_pages/help'
      expect(page).to have_content('Help')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Help'" do
      visit '/static_pages/help'
      expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help")
    end
  end

  describe "About page" do

    it "should have the content 'About Us'" do
      visit '/static_pages/about'
      expect(page).to have_content('About Us')
    end

    it "should have the title 'About Us'" do
      visit '/static_pages/about'
      expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us")
    end
  end

  describe "Contact page" do

    it "should have the content 'Contact'" do
      visit '/static_pages/about'
      expect(page).to have_content('Contact')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Contact'" do
      visit '/static_pages/about'
      expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact")
    end
  end

end
```

application.html.erb, which is saved under app/views/layouts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | <%= yield(:title) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all",
                                            "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

contact.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Contact') %>
<h1>Contact</h1>
<p>
  Contact Ruby on Rails Tutorial about the sample app at the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/contact">contact page</a>.
</p>
```

routes.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "static_pages/home"
  get "static_pages/help"
  get "static_pages/about"
  get "static_pages/contact"
end
```

static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

Comment: Where is `contact.html.erb` located in your file structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the limited information you're providing (I know it's hard to diagnose when you're a beginner, it gets easier).  It looks like you're telling your test to check your about page and checking for content that only exists in your contact page.